# Difference between instance variable and non static member

Tags: instance-variables, non-static

I am studying C++ from different sources and I find confusing that sometimes I encounter the term "Non-static member" and sometimes the term "Instance Variable".
For me, they can be used interchangeably as they both refer to members of a class that are different for each instance, and can be only accessed through an instance

I would like to know if these two terms are really synonyms or I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

"Members" are not just fields/properties of your class, but also the methods in your class. See [Working Draft, Standard for Programming
Language C++ - 9.2 Class members](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf):

> Members of a class are data members, member functions (9.3), nested types, and
>   enumerators.

"Instance variables", in most cases the term is used, is used to describe the non static "data members" of a class. So, to answer your question: "Instance variables" are a subset of "non-static members".

Comment: You are completely right, I overlooked the fact that members include methods as well.